# How to connect a point of X with a point of Y in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Good evening. I am trying to plot a fuzzy number so an element "140" is connected with it's membership function. I tried to plot one more curve above data curve, but that seemed not a good idea. Any advices are appreciated. Thanks for your time. Here's the code and the desired plot:

```
import numpy as np
import fuzzylab

x = np.linspace(130, 150, 1000)
y = fuzzylab.trimf(x, [133.3, 140, 147])



plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[desired plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MlUs.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `axvline` and `axhline` to draw lines at specific coordinates.

```
# Manual way
max_y = y.max()
max_x = x[y.argmax()]
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.axvline(x=max_x, ymin=0, ymax=0.95, c='r', lw=3)
plt.axhline(y=max_y, xmin=0, xmax=0.5, c='r', lw=3)
plt.show()
```

Note that `ymin`, `ymax`, `xmin` and `xmax` are in Axes coordinates (from 0 to 1, see [the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html)). Your example is not too bad, you can just fiddle with the numbers until you get something you like.

However, if you want this to be more generic, you'll need to use transforms, from data coordinates to Axes coordinates. You can do that like this:

```
# Generic way
max_y = y.max()
max_x = x[y.argmax()]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
# For some reason this was necessary, otherwise the limits would behave badly.
ax.set_xlim(ax.get_xlim())  
x_prop, y_prop = ax.transLimits.transform((max_x, max_y))
ax.axvline(x=max_x, ymin=0, ymax=y_prop, c='r', lw=3)
ax.axhline(y=max_y, xmin=0, xmax=x_prop, c='r', lw=3)
```

Here, `transLimits` transforms your `data` coordinates to `axes` coordinates. If you modify your `y` variable to be a bit skewed, the red lines will match the position automatically.

Output plot:

[image]